Can Congress pass a law that sets an incarcerated person free?
Imagine John Doe is incarcerated for a crime after exhausting all his appeals. Congress approves a bill, which is then signed into law, that, among a myriad of other things, sets John free.
Has this ever happened?: Is this possible (i.e. within the powers Congress has to put into law)?
The discussion of whether Congress would ever do that to release an incarcerated person or if a Presidential pardon would be the correct way to do it is beyond the legal scope of this question. Only if that is within the powers of a law.

While they're prohibited from writing a law that punishes a specific person or group (this is the "bill of attainder" restriction), I can't imagine why they couldn't do the opposite.

@Barmar I think there's probably a decent separation-of-powers argument to be made, though I also suspect that this would be legal.

Is this a law which changes sentencing rules, or a law which institutes a pardon in all but name, or something else?

Yes.
Assuming that the person is incarcerated under federal law, Congress can and has retroactively reduced sentences for federal crimes (sometimes resulting in a release from prison entirely) and indeed has done so rather recently.
And, at the federal government level, there is no prohibition on Congress passing "special legislation" that only affects select people. So called "private laws" that affect only one person or a small number of people are passed every year. The process for passing private laws is discussed here.
The Bill of Attainder clause of the U.S. Constitution prohibits Congress from passing a law that declares someone to be guilty of a crime. But the converse, a law that vacates someone's prison sentence, is not barred by the Bill of Attainder clause.
Congress would not generally have the power to vacate a sentence imposed under a state or local law that was valid at the time, although the U.S. Supreme Court, on rare occasions, does so by finding a state law prison sentence to be unconstitutional. Similarly, it is well established that the Presidential pardon power does not extend to state and local government established crimes.
This distinction is very material.

As of 2019, about 1,255,689 people currently behind bars in the United
States—or 87.7% out of a total of 1,430,805 prisoners—had been
convicted in state court for violating state criminal laws, rather
than in federal court for violating federal criminal laws.
The proportion of criminal cases brought in state court rather than
federal court is higher than 87.7% because misdemeanor and petty
offense prosecutions are disproportionately brought in state courts
and most criminal prosecutions involve misdemeanors and petty
offenses.
The number of trials conducted in each system is another way
to illustrate the relative size of the two criminal justice systems.
In Colorado, in 2002, there were approximately 40 criminal trials in
federal court, and there were 1,898 criminal trials (excluding
hundreds of quasi-criminal trials in juvenile cases, municipal cases
and infraction cases) in state courts, so only about 2% of criminal
trials took place in federal court. Most jury trials in the United
States (roughly five out of six jury trials conducted in any U.S.
Court) take place in criminal cases in state courts.

There might be some conceivable circumstances in which federal law could vacate a a particular state prison sentence (although probably not any circumstance present in Donald Trump's state court criminal cases), for example, as part of an international peace treaty, although I'm not aware of any precedents for cases where that has ever actually happened.
Obviously, of course, Congress can't set someone incarcerated by another country free just by passing a law that says that they should be released.

Interesting. I believe (but I'm not totally sure) this would be unconstitutional in Germany because it violates equality before the law to treat single individuals specially. (Pardons -- which are administered by the executive -- are an exception specifically aiming at solving situations where the equal application of the law is deemed unsatisfactory.)

Hm.  Art. 19 GG only has the prohibition of targeting individuals for laws that restrict their rights. On the other hand, the right to pardon is given to the executive, which may be read to imply that the legislative does not have it.

@Peter-ReinstateMonica Could very well be in Germany. Prosecutors in the U.S. sometimes make a similar separation of powers argument when legislation to reduce or eliminate sentences retroactively is proposed, but the courts in the U.S. have not backed them up.

"Obviously, of course, Congress can't set someone incarcerated by another country free just by passing a law that says that they should be released." They could sign a declaration of war against that foreign country if that person isn't released, however.

france
Yes, but it has never been done.
The constitution gives the Parliament authority to (emphasis mine):

[...]
The determination of serious crimes and other major offences and the penalties they carry; criminal procedure; amnesty; the setting up of new categories of courts and the status of members of the Judiciary;

French constitution, article 34
When this prerogative has been used, it has always been used as a wide-ranging measure, targeting thousand of persons at a time, but nothing prevents it.
--
Two minor points:

It could not be done in a law "amongst a myriad of other things". Riders are not allowed in French laws. They are found on a regular basis to be unconstitutional.

The French president has a distinct right to pardon, with different consequences (amnesty - the crime never occurred, it is forbidden to mention it / pardon - the crime occurred, but the President decided you could skip part of, or the entire time in jail)



The President of the Republic is vested with the power to grant individual pardons

French constitution, article 17

"the crime never occurred, it is forbidden to mention it" can you clarify what you mean by this ? I've seen an opinion from the constitutional court from 2013 that seems to specifically indicate that a law to that effect (making it illegal to mention an amnesty) is unconstitutional (at https://www.jurisexpert.net/diffamation-exception-de-verite-et-amnistie-un-cocktail-explosif/)

united-kingdom
Parliament can (in theory) legislate to do anything it wants - including quashing convictions.
And indeed, it did exactly this with the Post Office (Horizon System) Offences Act 2024, whose first section reads:

Every conviction to which this Act applies is quashed on the coming into force of this Act.

This was a response to the British Post Office scandal, which saw several hundred people erroneously convicted. It was felt that the normal process of going through an appeals process for every case would take too long, and cause additional suffering for people who had already being through a terrible ordeal; hence the Government and Parliament acted through legislation instead.
There were concerns that Parliament was overstepping the mark by effectively acting in a judicial manner; but the Act was passed anyway.

united-kingdom
The UK Government has released thousands of prisoners early to reduce overcrowding.
Hansard Society reports:

How delegated legislation is being used to tackle the prisons crisis
Thousands of prisoners will be released on license early, once they have completed 40% rather than 50% of their sentence, if a Statutory Instrument is approved by the House of Commons today (25 July 2024). This is not the first time delegated legislation has been used to address the prison overcrowding crisis by implementing what are significant and contentious policy changes.


This is targeting an entire sub-population identified by impersonal criteria like percentage of sentence served, nature of the crime etc. I think the question asked specifically about John ;-). What happens if parliament passes a law for all individuals born on day x in town y being in prison z (and John happens to be the only one meeting the criteria) is probably up to the courts. In America and probably in Germany the criteria must have a connection to the case though.

@Peter-ReinstateMonica at one time the House of Lords was the final jurisdiction of an appeal against conviction or sentence, but that ended in 2009 after the Constitutional Reform Act 2005. It is now the Supreme Court, but before then the answer would have been 'yes'.

@Peter-ReinstateMonica Parliament can make or unmake any law.

An Indemnity Act can certainly name an individual, e.g. the "Charles Beattie Indemnity Act 1956" which relieved Beattie of having to pay £9500 in fines owing to voting as an MP  while disqualified due to sitting on certain public boards. Release from prison should be no different.

@Lag In Germany, there are most certainly laws parliament cannot unmake; these are the entrenched clauses in the Basic Law. As a consequence, parliament can most certainly not make laws that violate those clauses. Moreover, even in places that lack such provisions, while a parliament may be able to nominally pass laws that violate certain basic human rights (e.g., condone murder at the German-German border), such laws are invalid and have no material effect (e.g., do not render murder legal).

@WeatherVane What is and is not allowed in the UK is a always bit murky, given the lack of a constitution. Charles Stross thinks that if push comes to shove, for example during a demon invasion, the sovereign is where the buck stops. Not the PM, not parliament, not the people...

@Peter-ReinstateMonica constitutions can be changed too.

@Peter-ReinstateMonica I meant the UK Parliament, not the Bundestag.

@WeatherVane Those provisions in the Basic Law cannot be changed (in their substance); they are called "eternity clauses". The people (however mediated) can pass a new constitution, but that is not the same, is it: It replaces the entire legal framework. Within this framework, those clauses are eternal.

The question asks about the legislature freeing a prisoner, but this example is about a statutory instrument, which is made by the executive (albeit with the legislature's consent). OTOH, the UK Parliament can legislate on anything it wants, including quashing convictions.
